# How to use a predefined value based on a range of another value

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

Scrapped my original question as this is perhaps a clearer version!

This is what I am trying to do.  Currently I get *'Only one expression can be specified n the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.'*emphasized text**

```
declare @X int

SET @X=(
SELECT B.ID, 
Case
When Getdate() Between '2012-11-01 00:00' AND '2013-10-31 23:59' then 731
When Getdate() Between '2012-11-01 00:00' AND '2013-10-31 23:59' then 1096
END FROM  Booking B)


Select 
B.Created - @X AS 'Bookings date less X'
From Booking B
```

Comment: What "flavour" of SQL are you using?

Comment: comma before X ??? Please add further information about your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do with the second bit there, but this should help you with the first (assuming you are using SQL Server)...

```
declare @x integer;

set @x = case WHEN Getdate() Between '2012-11-01 00:00' AND '2013-10-31 23:59' then -731 when Getdate() Between '2013-11-01 00:00' AND '2014-10-31 23:59' then 1 end;

print @x
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you're looking for a [case statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) and a [variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
DECLARE @X int

SELECT @X = 
    CASE WHEN Getdate() Between '2012-11-01 00:00' AND '2013-10-31 23:59' THEN -731
    ELSE
    CASE WHEN Getdate() Between '2013-11-01 00:00' AND '2014-10-31 23:59' THEN 1096
    ELSE
    NULL
    END
```

Then in some subsequent statement:

```
CASE WHEN B.Created < @X THEN 'Hello' ELSE 'Not Hello' END
```

Comment: Thanks Subterfuge, I've updated my question here to be a bit clearer, appreciate your time ;-)